# Windows 8 Hardware Diagnostics

Tags: windows, ssd, ntfs, diagnostic

I have a new high spec. Windows 8 Pro work station that has now BSOD three times in 5 days due to NTFS problems.  Is there a tool I can leave running after work that try to determine the root cause of these problems? I have a SSD, perhaps it's faulty?

===EDIT===

OSR Analysis here http://pastebin.com/72wZvCES

Comment: Did you check Windows' event logs? Even if the PC reboots automatically, there should be some entry. Also try writing down the error code as well as the location/originating library (if given).

Comment: Do what @ali786 said and get the minidump files (C:\Minidump) and analyze them online at [OSR Online](http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=analyze) and post the analysis to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and add the Pastebin link in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

See the minidump files.
BSOD (Blue Screen of Death ) will leave the root cause information in this file before restarting.

It will give error codes and some info, insert that information in your question - then you can get a proper solution... 
or contact with the support team of hardware or Microsoft for more info as you are saying it is new.

For more info about BSOD and minidump files:
http://www.howtogeek.com/163452/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-blue-screen-of-death/